# Pygame subsurface rectangle outside surface area

Tags: python, pygame

```
def screenshot():
scrnsht_t = datetime.now().strftime("%y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S")
if not os.path.exists("screenshots"):
    os.makedirs("screenshots")
screenshot_zone = screen.subsurface(pg.Rect(0, HEIGHT/5+5, WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pg.image.save(screenshot_zone, f"screenshots\{scrnsht_t}.png")
```

Error:

```py
screenshot_zone = screen.subsurface(pg.Rect(0, HEIGHT/5+5, WIDTH, HEIGHT))
```

> ValueError: subsurface rectangle outside surface area

Answer (score 0):

A rectangle of size and position *(0, HEIGHT/5+5, WIDTH, HEIGHT)* cannot lie completely in the surface, because if the rectangle starts at `HEIGHT/5+5`, the height of the subsurface cannot be `HEIGHT`. The maximum height of the subsurface is `HEIGHT - (HEIGHT/5+5)`.

Change the subsurface rectangle:

```py
offset_y = HEIGHT//5 + 5 
screenshot_zone = screen.subsurface(pg.Rect(0, offset_y, WIDTH, HEIGHT-offset_y))
```